# How to set the YARN queue when submitting a Spark application from the Airflow SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, airflow, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Airflow and the SparkSubmitOperator.  I can see that Spark applications are submitted to the 'root.default' queue out the box when targeting YARN.

Simple question - how does one set a custom queue name ?

```
wordcount = SparkSubmitOperator(
    application='/path/to/wordcount.py',
    task_id="wordcount",
    conn_id="spark_default",
    dag=dag
)
```

p.s. I have read the docs:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.html

Thanks

Comment: `SparkSubmitOperator` has argument `conf` which is a dictionary. Try setting the key `spark.yarn.queue` with your queue value

Comment: Thanks but not working unfortunately.  I can see conf is set to use 'default' as the queue, but --queue is still 'root.default'.

airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: ['spark-submit', '--master', 'yarn', '--conf', 'spark.yarn.queue=default', '--name', 'airflow-spark', '--queue', 'root.default'

Comment: p.s the code:

wordcount = SparkSubmitOperator(
    application='/path/to/wordcount.py',
    conf={'spark.yarn.queue': 'default'},

Comment: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: ['spark-submit', '--master', 'yarn', '--conf', 'spark.yarn.queue=default', '--name', 'airflow-spark', '--queue', 'root.default'

Comment: Yes I had the exact same problem, setting the configuration gets overridden by that extra setting in the connection. Well spotted.

Answer (score 4):

I can see now that --queue value is coming from the Airflow spark-default connection:

```
Conn Id = spark_default
Host = yarn
Extra = {"queue": "root.default"}
```

Go to Admin Menu > Connections, select spark default and edit it :
Change Extra `{"queue": "root.default"}` to `{"queue": "default"}` in the Airflow WebServer UI.

This of course means an Airflow connection is required for each queue.

[image]

Comment: You saved my night, bro... This should be documented

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, there are at least **two** ways to do this:

1. Via the Spark connection, as Phillip answered.
2. Via the a `--conf` parameter, which Dustan mentions in a comment.

From my testing, if there's a `queue` set in the Connection's `Extra` field, that is used regardless of what you pass into the `SparkSubmit` conf.

However, if you **remove** `queue` from `Extra` in the Connection, and send it in the `SparkSubmitOperator` conf arg like below, YARN will show it properly.

```
conf={
       "spark.yarn.queue": "team_the_best_queue",
       "spark.submit.deployMode": "cluster",
       "spark.whatever.configs.you.have" = "more_config",
}
```